# JS libraries not loaded on page with multiple form webparts?

Tags: web-part, jquery, form, libraries, jquery-ui

I'm struggeling with a weird behavior on some of my pages. It occurs both on plain site pages and on web part pages:

I have built various form-webparts and exported them. They all are referencing js-libraries stored in a public document-library. When I upload one of the exported webparts to a page, everything works fine, the libraries in the webparts are loaded and the sripts are executed.

Now when I add multiple webparts to one page, only one webpart is working. E.g. when I have a web part page and add 2 or more to it, only the one below the 2 others is loaded. All other webparts fail and there is the javascript error, stating that "Object doesn't support this property or method" - like the libraries with the plugins wouldn't have been loaded.

Is it simply impossible to have multiple form-webparts which all reference different js-libraries on one page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if js library is already on page if it is - don't add it second time if it is not on page - load it.

Comment: Thanks, avoiding duplicates seem to work. Though I noticed that on my "Development"-SP Sites referencing libraries multiple times and even mixing versions works smoothly.

Comment: In addition to @m.jedrzej: Everyone, make sure to always use "jQuery" instead of "$"! Will save you a lot of trouble ;)